# Unexpected behaviour with Urllib in Python

Tags: python, urllib

My system is not behind any proxy.

```
params = urllib.urlencode({'search':"August Rush"})
f = urllib.urlopen("http://www.thepiratebay.org/search/query", params)
```

This goes onto an infinite loop(Or just hangs). I can obviously get rid of this and use FancyUrlOpener and create the query myself rather than passing it parameters. But, I think doing the way I'm doing now is a better and cleaner approach.

Edit: This was more of a networking problem in which my Ubuntu workstation was configured to a different proxy. Had to do certain changes and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code works fine for me, with Python 2.7.2 on Windows.

Have you tried using a http-debugging tool, like [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see the actual conversation going between your program and the site?

If you run Fiddler2 on port 8888 on localhost, you can do this to see the request and response:

```
import urllib
proxies = {"http": "http://localhost:8888"}
params = urllib.urlencode({'search':"August Rush"})
f = urllib.urlopen("http://www.thepiratebay.org/search/query", params, proxies)
print len(f.read())
```

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to Fiddler.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
import urllib

params = urllib.urlencode({'q': "August Rush", 'page': '0', 'orderby': '99'})
f = urllib.urlopen("http://www.thepiratebay.org/s/", params)

with open('text.html', 'w') as ff:
    ff.write('\n'.join(f.readlines()))
```

I opened http://www.thepiratebay.org with Google Chrome with network inspector enabled. I put "August Rush" into the search field and pressed 'Search'. Then i analyzed the headers sent and did the code above.